# xcolor - how to use a private list of colors instead of one of the predefined lists

Tags: color, package-options

I have been gathering colours from the uff.rip/@farben bot on Mastodon which posts new ones several times a day. To use them I have extracted the RGB data and created a farben.def file in the same format as svgnam.def, dvipsnam.def, etc.

Does the xcolor package have any hook to allow the use of a user-created .def file? It would be nice to be able to load it with a syntax like \usepackage[def=farben]{xcolor}

Comment: no but you can simply `\input` it (or call it .sty and use `\usepackage`)

Comment: Or you can create a package like for example [xkcdcolors](https://ctan.org/pkg/xkcdcolors?lang=en) (disclaimer: I wrote that)

Comment: Of course; a package is not a problem. But as the file format is the same as those supplied with xcolor, it would seem to be more elegant as an argument to an option.